# Is it possible to dynamically control the behavior of a layer when forward and backward in caffe python?

Tags: python, caffe

The requirements are the following:

1. Will use code, especially python to control the forward and backward of a net.
2. Some layers not very much are customized, for instance, using PythonLayer to implement its customized functions.
3. During some forwards or backwards the customized layers will behave as, say, process 1; during others they will behave as, say, process 2, etc. We think set some variable as flag in these customized layers would satisfy this requirement.

Could these requirements be met in caffe, especially caffe python? If not, could caffe2?

Comment: Do you mean Caffe Python layer or pycaffe?

Comment: BTW, are you really know it?

Comment: Our intention is to realize these requirements. If Caffe Python layer could, we use Caffe Python layer. If pycaffe has such capacity, we would switch to use pycaffe. PythonLayer is one feature of pycaffe, isn't it?